# WikiMedia. Search with french accents. Result differ's

Tags: search, mediawiki

I have MediaWiki 1.19 with MySQL 5.1.58 and php-5.3.6 installed in a SANDBOX.
On the MediaWiki, I do a search with the word ''Québec'' or ''Quebec'' and I have different results...

Is there anything I can change in Apache or MySQL to fix that issue? Like adding AddDefaultCharset utf-8 to Apache (which I did and does not fix anything)..?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the collation of the database/tables, by selecting one that equates `é` with `e` that is most suitable for your needs, such as `utf8_general_ci`.

You should carefully select one based on your requirements, unfortunately there are a lot to choose from; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

MySQL also offers some nice detail with [Examples of the Effect of Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/charset-collation-effect.html).